# What's the theme here? (#2)

Tags: visual, rebus

Another group of pictures that have a theme:

1.--[image]
2.-- [image]
3.--[image]
4.--[image]
5.--[image]
6.--[image]
7.--[image]
8.--[image]
9.--[image]
10.--[image]
11.--[image]
12.--[image]
13.--[image]

**HINTS:**

> a) The answer has **nothing** to do with South Park,
> b) all of the images can be represented by a *single* word, and
> c) each **word** will broadly relate to the theme of *animals*, and a subset of that theme will be the **answer**.

Comment: I think it's something related to gun violence in the United States. A lot of images depict acts of violence and guns.

Comment: Is [tag:knowledge] of South Park required?

Comment: @ferret Maybe for #12 and #13... For the others, I'd say no.

Comment: ***Blame Canada!***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that what we're looking at here are:

> words that are used as groups of animals. It's difficult to pinpoint exactly what words you're looking for, but here are my best guesses:
>
> (1) an army of frogs 
> (2) a band of gorillas 
> (3) a pitying of doves (intended: a **bed** of clams) 
> (4) a brace of oxen 
> (5) a parliament of owls (intended: a **congress** of baboons) 
> (6) a skulk of foxes (intended: a **crossing** of zebra) 
> (7) a gang of elk 
> (8) a horde of crows (intended: horde of **hamsters** :) 
> (9) a murder of crows 
> (10) a shadow of jaguars (intended: a **pod** of whales)
> (11) a school of fish 
> (12) a scold of jays (intended: **sleuth** of bears) 
> (13) a mob of kangaroos (intended: a **rabble** of butterflies)

Comment: You get the prize! I added my intended answers for clarification purposes. In #13 (and in many other SP scenes) the mob is saying "Rabble, rabble, rabble!"

Comment: These words are called [collective nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_terms_of_venery,_by_animal)